# How can I force trailing slash, and optimize for search engines in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

I have a .htaccess file, but I'm not sure if it'll actually harm me instead of help me. How should I do this better to have search engines not penalize me with duplicate content?

I don't want them to rank login.php or /login, just /login/. And simiarly, if someone visits login.php or /login, I'd like them to be forced to /login/. How can I do this and optimize correctly?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^login/$ login.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^register/$ register.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^recover/$ recover.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^recover/([a-z0-9]+)/$ recover.php?code=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^game/([a-z0-9-]+)/$ game.php?game=$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have some new redirect rules to redirect to pretty URLs:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(register|login|recover)(?:\.php)?[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(game|recover)\.php\?code=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^(register|login|recover)/$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(game|recover)/([a-z0-9]+)/$ $1.php?code=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Would these be used as well as my existing rules? And would the `/login` be re-directed to `/login/` with this too? And is this good for SEO?

Comment: Test updated rules and answer to all of your questions is yes

Comment: Thank you so much anubhava. Is there anything you'd recommend I change with my code above? I want it to be perfect for search engines. I'll compress it so it's like yours (with `register|login|recover`) but is there anything else I should add? Cheers

Comment: Just change 302 to 301 once you've verified everything and SEO ranks will reflect that in due time.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I changed it to 301 now because it's not on a live site, it's a site I'm about to launch. :) So not yet ranked. But should I add the `R=301` to my code in the original post?

Comment: yes that's correct, change it to 301 wherever I had 302

Comment: But what about my original code above in my question? Should I also add the 301 to any of those?

Comment: You don't need any of that with the code I've provided.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73882/discussion-between-invidious-and-anubhava). - Can I ask you something quickly?